# Simple: What is the "+" operator doing (C bits)?

Tags: c, bit

I looked around for quite a bit and I can't seem to find the answer to this seemingly simple question: what exactly IS "+" or "-" in C (bits)?

For example, what is the representation when 1 is added to 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111?

I ask this because I'm reading through some code and I don't know what

```
 ~0 + 1
```

is doing.  I mean, we can't add 1 to 4294967295 right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course we can. Since you didn't specify the type of any of your literals, 'int' is assumed. `~0` is `-1`, as you indicated, and `-1 + 1` is zero.

If on the other hand these are unsigned numbers, then you have an integer overflow. The actual add instruction deep inside your PC still returns zero, it just sets a 'carry' flag to let C know that something weird happened. In the C spec, the result of an integer overflow is undefined, so you /probably/ get zero, but you can't rely on it.

Comment: Unsigned integer overflow is never undefined, it is explicitly defined to wrap around.  Only signed integer overflow causes problems, and it only causes undefined behavior in certain circumstances.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I thought ~0 was 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111??

Comment: Pauliwago: It is, and in signed numbers (which is the default in C if you don't explicitly state otherwise) the all-ones value is interpreted as `-1`. Read up on "two's complement" numbers - it's the way integers are stored in memory on your PC.

Comment: My answer contains a link to information on two's complement.

Comment: To complement Dietrich Epp's remark with a quote, C99's 6.2.5:9 says “A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type.”

Answer (score 4):

The answer will depend on what representation your computer uses for signed numbers.

- In "Two's Complement" format, `~0 == -1`, so `~0 + 1 == 0`.
- In "Ones' Complement" format, `~0 == -0`, so `~0 + 1 == 1`.
- In "Sign-magnitude" format, `~0 == INT_MIN`, so `~0 + 1 == INT_MIN + 1`.

The result is guaranteed to be defined on all systems.

**On the other hand,** if you use unsigned numbers you will always get the same result.

- `~n` is defined to be the maximum value of `n`'s type, minus `n`.  So `~0u` is `UINT_MAX`.
- `x + y` is guaranteed to wrap around, so the standard guarantees that `UINT_MAX + 1 == 0` on all systems.
- Therefore, `~0u + 1 == 0u` on all systems, guaranteed.

As you can see, this is the same behavior as two's complement, which explains the popularity of two's complement.  Systems which don't use two's complement are rare these days, not counting bigint libraries.

Comment: One caveat: On ones' complement implementation that does not support negative zeroes, the behaviour of `~0` is undefined (C99 §6.2.6.2).  This is a bit sad.

Answer (score 1):

Let's stick to a smaller number to be easier to see what is happening.

A 4 bit number would be `0000`. Start with `1111` now add one to it. The value is now `1 0000` which you will see as `0000`.

It is just like in normal base ten addition. We have `9` then we have `0` in the ones place and `1` in the tens place. If we have a bigger number than we have bits the counter just rolls over to 0 and starts over.

Now, this is simplified to talk about positive numbers. If the int is signed, you go from the maximum positive to the maximum negative and loop back around to max positive eventually do to the way negative and positive numbers are stored in binary.

Comment: What does packed BCD have to do with anything?

Comment: Yeah, that was boneheaded. Not paying attention. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
2^32=4294967296
```

So, `2^32-1` is the maximum value for a 32-bit unsigned integer (32 binary digits). 2^32 is the number of possible values.
The 4294967295 is because integers start at 0, but our counting starts at 1.
this is a integer range, when you add 1 to this number, it goes out of integer range, that's why we cant add one to 4294967295.

`+` is an addition arithmetic operator & `-` is substraction arithmetic operator

Answer (score 0):

Technically, C doesn't add or extract. The compiler translates it into assembly code, which gets translated into machine code. The architecture should have an `ADD` instruction.

I believe the operation can be done in several ways, using basic logic gates.

Regardless, this [book](http://www.scribd.com/doc/53115839/MicroProcessor-Design#page=53) has some information.

What you may also be interested in is how negative numbers are represented in binary and how this fits into arithmetic operations.

The common format used is called **twos complement**. You can read more on how this works [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html).